# How to add an action listener to JDialog Textfield in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JDialog form in a Java Swing app. If the user enters valid inputs and clicks the Ok button, the data will save to the DB, but if not valid, a message box should display with the appropriate message, and then the dialog form should remain visible until the user clicks the Cancel button or entered valid input and clicks the OK button. I'm very new to Java Swing. Any sample code is highly appreciated.

Here is what I want to do:

```
 private void saveOnOKCklicked() {
  String string1ToValidate = textField1.getText();
  String string2ToValidate = textField2.getText();
  
 // here I want to do the validation for the Dialog box and the fields but not knowing how to start.
    // Though I have read some documents online but do not fully understand how to do it.
}
```

This is what I have done so far: I want to call this method when the ok button is clicked.

```
  private void onOk() {
            name = nameTextField.getText();
            inputToValidate = inputField.getText();
           okClick = true;
           dispose();
}

private ActionListener oKButtonClicked() {
  return new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          String checkInput = inputField.getText();
          if (checkInput is valid){
             continue with the process
      }
          else show a message box and dialog form remains visible 
      }
  };
}
```

But this one only shows the message box if the input is not valid. but the dialog form closes when the message box's ok button is clicked. I want the dialog form to remain open until the input is valid before it closes when the ok button is clicked. please, help.

Comment: Use ```JOptionPane``` to display an error message. Plenty of examples exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete runnable solution.

You're welcome.

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog
{
  public MyDialog()
  {
    txtField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btn = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

    txtField.setText("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    getContentPane().add(txtField);

    btn.setText("OK");
    btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
      {
        btnActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    getContentPane().add(btn);

    pack();     
  }

  private void btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                    
  {                                        
    if (txtField.getText().equals("XXX"))
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component)evt.getSource(),"Good input, closing.");
      dispose();
    }
    else
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component)evt.getSource(),"Bad input, correct please.");      
    }
  }                                   

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
  }
                  
  private javax.swing.JButton btn;
  private javax.swing.JTextField txtField;                
}
```

Comment: It works exactly as expected, thank you so much. @ePortfel